# Logical "OR" of two dataframes with string values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to make logical "OR" of two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([{'call_id':'aa','486':'2021-09-01','487':0}])
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([{'call_id':'aa','503':1,'487':1}])   

df1 = df1.set_index('call_id')
df2 = df2.set_index('call_id')   
df3 = df1 | df2
```

and wished result is:

```
            486          487  503
    call_id               
    aa      2021-09-01     1    1
```

So, if some value in one df is null , then result should have value from second df. If one value is zero and second is 1 then result should  be as logical "OR"

Comment: Do you mean `print(df1.combine_first(df2))` ?

Comment: No. combine_first gives "0" for "487"

Comment: Are you values only 0/1 ? Then you can use `df1.combine(df2, np.logical_or)` or make your func. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine.html  (or use `.combine_first` and first replace `0` with `np.nan`)